# Start/enable Timer again after cancellation

Tags: java, timer

I have the following function to stop my scheduler:

```
import javax.ejb.Timer;

// call this remote method with the Timer info that has to be canceled
@AccessTimeout(value = 20, unit = TimeUnit.MINUTES)
public void cancelTimer(String timerInfo) {
    try {
        for (Timer timer : timerService.getTimers()) {
            if (timerInfo.equals(timer.getInfo())) {
                timer.cancel();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

Which will be invoked:

```
cancelTimer("scheduleImagesFromFolder");
```

But now my question:
How can I enable the schedule again?

My Timer.class is a **javax.ejb.Timer**

Comment: No, it´s not duplicated.... It´s another Timer class....

Comment: You can potentially get its handle and reinstate it, but otherwise it is very similar to standard Timer classes i.e. once canceled, they are not normally reenabled, you need to create a new one instead. See here: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html#bnbpb